# JavaScript. Detect when html element is loaded from another js script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect html element which is loaded from 3rd party library for example:
div with title "box". It should should be detected without using delays.

```
function createBox() {
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var domString =
        '<div title="box" style="border:solid" class="container"><button>btn</button><span class="intro">Hello</span> <span id="name"> World!</span></div>';
      var html = parser.parseFromString(domString, "text/html");
      document.body.append(html.body.firstChild);
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      // Do something after 2 seconds
      createBox();
    }, 2000);

    let box = document.querySelector('[title="box"]');
    if (box != null) {
      console.log("box is detected");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know where the element is going to be appended, you can attach a MutationObserver to the parent, which will run a callback when a child is appended:

```js
function createBox() {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var domString =
    '<div title="box" style="border:solid" class="container"><button>btn</button><span class="intro">Hello</span> <span id="name"> World!</span></div>';
  var html = parser.parseFromString(domString, "text/html");
  document.body.append(html.body.firstChild);
}

console.log('start');
setTimeout(function() {
  // Do something after 2 seconds
  createBox();
}, 2000);

new MutationObserver(() => {
  const box = document.querySelector('[title="box"]');
  if (box) {
    console.log("box is detected");
  }
})
  .observe(document.body, { childList: true });
```

If you *don't* know where the element is going to be appended, but you can identify the element (such as with a selector), you can still use a MutationObserver, but it'll have to watch for deep changes via `subtree: true`, which can be expensive on large pages which change a lot:

```js
console.log('start');
function createBox() {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var domString =
    '<div title="box" style="border:solid" class="container"><button>btn</button><span class="intro">Hello</span> <span id="name"> World!</span></div>';
  var html = parser.parseFromString(domString, "text/html");
  outer.append(html.body.firstChild);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  // Do something after 2 seconds
  createBox();
}, 2000);

new MutationObserver((_, observer) => {
  const box = document.querySelector('[title="box"]');
  if (box) {
    console.log("box is detected");
    observer.disconnect();
  }
})
  .observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

```html
<div id="outer">outer</div>
```

Comment: FYI, official doc and browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver